# How to change Googlemap user-location blue dot to an image of choice in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, xcode8

I am using Xcode 8.0. I integrated Google map iOS SDK to my project using CocoaPods.

I enable user current location using via `mapView.myLocationEnabled = true;` But i need to customize this blue dot image when this screen loading time.

I exactly mean that any delegate method for customize the blue dot mark like in Google Maps instead of Apple map (`- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView: (MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>) annotation`) iOS SDK.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Look into official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker), scroll down to section "Change the marker color" or "Customize the marker image"

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the object from class `GMSMarker` and set the `icon` property with `UIImage` of your choice and it should work.

This is is the simplest way of customizing the marker on Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can change *blue dot* image. However, there is a work around for the same.

You can hide the default button like this:

```
mapView.myLocationEnabled = NO;
```

Create a custom `GMSMarker`, set it at exact position of user location like this:

```
 GMSMarker *userLocationMarker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition: userLocation];
 userLocationMarker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomMarkerImage"];
 userLocationMarker.map = mapView;
```